# Kibana scripted field - text to timestamp conversion parse exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

I am unable to convert a text field `ts1` in my ES index (sample value `2017-09-30 04:53:39.412496Z`) to timestamp by using scripted fields in Kibana. The `SimpleDateFormat` expression works in Java, just not in Elasticsearch. [This](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/converting-a-string-date-to-a-date-field-using-scripted-fields-in-kibana/108952) mentions a similar problem but the solution doesn't work for me.

Query

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "test1" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": """new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'").parse(doc['ts1'].value).getTime()"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
{
  "took": 76,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 3,
        "index": "<index_name>",
        "node": "-TjsxK4-QsqgLQRQ-DSKGQ",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)",
            """new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'").parse(doc['ts1'].value).getTime()""",
            "                                                                      ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": """new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'").parse(doc['ts1'].value).getTime()""",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": """Unparseable date: "04""""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Java Code that works -

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class Main{

    public static void main(String []args){
        String text2 = "2017-09-30 04:53:39.123123Z";

        SimpleDateFormat s2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
        try {
            System.out.println(s2.parse(text2).getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` or just `Instant`. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also, works? Your Java code produced 1506747342123 on my computer, according to [Epoch Unix Time Stamp Converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) that’s 09/30/2017 @ 4:55am (UTC), so not exactly the 4:53 from the string.

Comment: It follows from the reason, `Unparseable date: "04"`, that your formatter is trying to parse the string `04` (not `2017-09-30 04:53:39.123123Z`). I don’t know how that can be.